# Email encode in text input using

Tags: php, html, email, encoding, character-encoding

I want to encode an email id in a text box. An email id is saved in database. When page loads i retrieve email id from database using php and display in text input and when i see the email id in page source then the email id should be encoded. How to do this using php and html?

Comment: What do you mean with "encoded" ? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function encode_email($e) {
  $output = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($e); $i++) { $output .= '&#'.ord($e[$i]).';'; }
  return $output;
}

 echo(encode_email('email@in.com'));
```

Comment: It throws a notice as `$output` is not initiated before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have tried with the same encoding method only. But in page source the text input is displaying as  <input type="text" id="edit-mail" value="&amp;#115;&amp;#115;&amp;#64;&amp;#100;&amp;#100;&amp;#46;&amp;#99;&amp;#111;&amp;#109;"  />  
and in UI text input its displaying as &#115;&#115;&#64;&#100;&#100;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;    
and not displaying actual email-id in UI text input. How to solve this problem?